# How to scroll view up as new line is added into UITextView instance?

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4, uiscrollview, uitextview

I've successfully setup a scroll view that move some text fields and a text view up in case they are hidden by keyboard. However, when the text view received some text that goes beyond the first line the next lines are obviously hidden by keyboard. So, I'm looking for a trick to move up/down the view each time a new line is added/removed into/from the UITextview instance.

Thx for helping,

Stephane

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement the

```
- (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text
```

method on your UITextView delegate, count the number of newlines in the textviews text, calculate how far you have to scroll, and scroll. (This method is called every time the user types a character.)

Alternatively you can go the easier route and scroll far enough to display your entire `UITextView`. If the user types more than fits into the textview, the textview will start scrolling automatically.

Answer (score 1):

Use `scrollRectToVisible:animated:` or `setContentOffset:animated:` - in your case, the first, as in:

```
[scrollView scrollRectToVisible:textField.frame animated:YES];
```

You may also need to scroll your text field contents to visible, but I think that should happen automatically.

Answer (score 0):

So if you compile previous answers :

Just set your `textView.delegate` as self and your `viewController` as `<UITextViewDelegate>` and :

```
- (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text {
    [textView scrollRangeToVisible:range];
    return YES;
}
```